# GenSA simulated annealing solver of R gives EXACTLY the same result regardless of settings

Tags: r, simulated-annealing

I've been using R's "GenSA" package for simulated annealing to solve a very complicated high dimensional optimization problem (63 unknowns). I found that every time I run GenSA I get exactly the same minimum (which is by no means the global minimum) regardless of my settings of temperature, maxit, even random seed, etc.. Even the trace matrix shows exactly the same current solution traces. The running time can be long or short depending on these parameters, but the algorithm always finds the same (local) minimum in the earlier stage and was never able to move on.

What parameters should I try to tune in order for GenSA to find other potential optimums?

Comment: I am not familiar with this particular package, but: if you know the result is not the global optimum, do you know the parameters that will give a better result? Can you feed these numbers into the model as starting values? (I note that you didn't list varying the starting values for parameters in your list of things you have tried - was that an oversight or intended?)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do have a better solution from another solver, but I don't want to use this information, as the problem is only a test case. I am only concerned that the GenSA function cannot get any other candidate solution. This doesn't sound right for SA algorithms. If I do provide a better solution to GenSA, it can improve it a little bit, but it can't find this or any other solutions on its own so far.